# Can I know my position sorted by reputation?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I can find myself in the [list of stackoverflow user sorted by their reputations](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) only by searching my user name.

What I want to know is: how do I get my position by number?

For example,

```
Name             Position
----------------------------
Jon Skeet           1 
Darin Dimitrov      2
..                  ..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rank as per your reputation is #68191.

Go to [Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) -> Select [Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) -> Select [All Time](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow)
Search for your name.

> [image]

However you will get your name at top by default like this:

> [image]

Comment: Or go to your profile, and click the `"top X% this Y"` link at the top of your reputation summary. Filter the resulting list by `"All Time"` to get your overall rank.